# Does Sendgrid Charge You Per Recipient?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Sendgrid's free limit is 100 emails per day. However, does that number count for cc's and bcc's? If I emailed 3 people in the same email, does that count as 3 or 1 emails? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They do. You can real quick test this in any environment by setting a few cc's and watch the numbers climb relative to the number of cc's you add in.

Comment: Is this just relative to cc/bcc - I mean, will the count increase if I put all recpeints in the `To` field? Does this also apply even if all recepients are in same domain?